# EventServiceProvider laravel 5

Tags: events, laravel

I am digging down the code of laravel 5 to understand it better. I started from index page and I am stuck at register part at the moment.

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
/**
* Register the service provider.
*
* @return void
*/

    public function register()
    {
      $this->app->singleton('events', function($app)
      {
          return (new Dispatcher($app))->setQueueResolver(function() use ($app)
          {
            **return $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue');**
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

I don't understand the part "$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue');". "Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue" is interface not a class. It should throw an error message for this process. however i don't see any error message. I assume that it's not called at this time?

It would be appreciated if you can explain what's happening here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of minutes investigating the classes and came up with the following:

Please take a look at the https://github.com/illuminate/queue laravel/framework repository subtree split.

The interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue` is implemented by all queue types available by default:

- `BeanstalkdQueue`
- `RedisQueue`
- `SqsQueue`
- `NullQueue`
- `SyncQueue`
- `DatabaseQueue`
- `IronQueue`

The Laravel IoC conatainer should resolve one of these when calling `$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue')` so I do not think that the application will fail, when executing this lines of code.

Unfortunately I could not find the location where a specific Queue implementation is set for the IoC container, I will update my answer as soon as I found out.